# C++ - Initializing dynamic set with an initializer list in a class

Tags: c++

I am trying to initialize `set<string_view>` dynamic class member with an initializer list. It is mad easy when it is not a pointer to a set, but I don't really know how to do that in that instance.

```
class Textpool {
public:
   Textpool() = default;
   Textpool(const std::initializer_list<std::experimental::string_view> &StringList);

   ~Textpool() = default;
private:
   std::set<std::experimental::string_view> *StringSet_;
};
```

It would look like that if it wasn't a pointer:

```
Textpool::Textpool(const std::initializer_list<std::experimental::string_view> &StringList) : StringSet_{StringList} {}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your member must be a pointer, then it must also be initialized to point to something. Note that defaulting the ctor/dtor is a usually bad idea if you have pointer members.

However, assuming you deal with that, is it not as simple as (whitespace added for clarity)

```
Textpool::Textpool(const std::initializer_list<std::experimental::string_view> &StringList)
  : StringSet_(new std::set<std::experimental::string_view>{StringList})
 {
 }
```

?